# Recuperar váriavel através de requisições ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Tenho os seguintes campos:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nomefiltrar" style="color:#E4CDAC; font-size: 17px; font-
        family:Arial">Nome</label>
   <p>

   <input type="text" class="teste" id="nomefiltrar" name="nomefiltrar" />


   </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-roxo btn_carrega_conteudo" id="teste">Filtrar</button>
</div>
```

Preciso recuperar o valor do campo "nomefiltrar" e enviar através do método post para a página "pdf_clientes.php".

Tentei algo como:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.btn_carrega_conteudo').click(function(){
                    if($('#nomefiltrar').val().length > 0){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'pdf_clientes.php',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: { nomefiltrar: $('#nomefiltrar').val() },
                            success: function(data){
                                alert('Teste');
                            }
                        });
                    }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Até estou recebendo o alert que a requisição foi completada, porém, ao dar o post na página pdf_clientes.php, não consigo recuperar o valor do campo nomefiltrar.

pdf_clientes.php:

```
$nome_filtrar = $_POST['nomefiltrar'];
<h1>{$nome_filtrar}</h1>
```

Segue meu código completo:

consulta_clientes.php:

```
<?php include_once("registra_pessoa.php");
    $grupo = filtraPessoas();



    if(!$_SESSION['usuario']){
        header('Location: index.php?erro=1');
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ocultaForm(tag){
                $(tag).show();
            }
        </script>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Despesas</title>

        <!-- jquery - link cdn -->

          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"/></script>


        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- bootstrap - link cdn -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.btn_carrega_conteudo').click(function(){
                    if($('#nomefiltrar').val().length > 0){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'pdf_clientes.php',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: { nomefiltrar: $('#nomefiltrar').val() },
                            success: function(data){
                                alert('Teste');
                            }
                        });
                    }
            });
        });


        </script>


    </head>

    <body>

<!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar-transparente">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barranavegacao">
                        <span class="sr-only">Alternar navegação</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a href="home.php" class="navbar-brand">
                       <span class="img-logo">Despesas</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barranavegacao">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Cadastro
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="inserir_pessoa.php">Cadastro de Clientes</a></li>
                          <li><a href="inserir_produto.php">Cadastro de Produtos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown active">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Consultas
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="consulta_clientes.php">Consulta de Clientes</a></li>
                          <li><a href="consulta_produtos.php">Consulta de Produtos</a></li>
                          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="consulta_contas.php">Consulta de Contas a Pagar</a></li>
                          <li><a href="consulta_contas_receber.php">Consulta de Contas a Receber</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Financeiro
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="inserir_conta.php">Contas a Pagar</a></li>
                          <li><a href="inserir_recebimento.php">Contas a Receber</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>


                    </ul>

                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="">Ajuda</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divisor" role="separator">
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="sair.php">Sair</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



            </div>
        </nav>
        <br><br><br><br><br>


        <div class="container">
        <div class="thumb">
        <a href="pdf_clientes.php" target="_blank">
        <img src="imagens/printer.png">
        </a>
        <div class="desc"><span style="color:white">Imprimir Relatório</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="filtraresultados" name="filtraresultados" src="imagens/search.png" style="cursor:pointer" "/>
        <div class="desc"><span style="color:white">Filtrar Resultados</span></div>
        </div>


        </div>


        <br>

        <div class="container">


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomefiltrar" style="color:#E4CDAC; font-size: 17px; font-family:Arial">Nome</label>
                <p>

                <input type="text" class="teste" id="nomefiltrar" name="nomefiltrar" />


            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-custom btn-roxo btn_carrega_conteudo" id="teste">Filtrar</button>
        </div>



<br>



        <script>
            filtraresultados.addEventListener("click", function() {
                ocultaForm('form');
            }, false);
        </script>

        <script>
            filtraresultados.addEventListener("click", function() {
                ocultaFormBotao('input');
            }, false);
        </script>






        <div class="container divconsultas">

                <table class="table">
            <thread>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Nome</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Data de nascimento</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Telefone</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Endereço</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Editar</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Excluir</td>
                </tr>
            </thread>
                <?php
                if (is_array($grupo) || is_object($grupo)){
                foreach($grupo as $pessoa){
                 ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["nome"]?> </td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["data_formatada"]?> </td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["telefone"]?> </td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["endereco"]?></td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma">

                             <form align="center" action="alterar_pessoa.php" name="alterar" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?=$pessoa["id"]?>>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn editar cor" value="Editar" name="Editar" class="btn btn-default">
                             </form>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <form align="center" action="registra_pessoa.php" name="excluir" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?=$pessoa["id"]?>>
                                <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="excluir"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn editar excluir" onclick="msgSucesso()" value="Excluir" name="excluir" class="btn btn-default">
                            </form>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


                </div>

                    <script>
                        function msgSucesso(){
                            alert('Pessoa excluida com sucesso');
                        }
                    </script>


                <?php
                }
            }else{
                echo('Ainda não existem clientes cadastrados');
            }

                ?>

            </table>
        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

pdf_clientes.php:

```
<?php
    include_once("registra_pessoa.php");
    include("./MPDF57/mpdf.php");
    $nome_filtrar = $_POST['nomefiltrar'];
    $pessoas = filtraPessoas();
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->setDisplayMode("fullpage");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1 align='center'>Relatório de Clientes</h1> <hr/>");

            $html = "
            <table class='tabela'>
            <thread>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</span></th>
                    <th>Data de nascimento</span></th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                </tr>
            </thread>
            <tbody>
            ";
                foreach($pessoas as $pessoa){

                    $html = $html ." <tr>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["nome"]} </td>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["data_formatada"]} </td>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["telefone"]} </td>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["endereco"]} </td>
                    </tr>";
                }

                $html = $html ."
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <h1>{$nome_filtrar}</h1>
                ";

    $css = file_get_contents('pdf_estilo.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($css, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit();

?>
```

Função registra_pessoa.php:

```
function filtraPessoas(){
    $grupo = '';
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $teste = $_POST['nomefiltrar'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, nome, DATE_FORMAT(nascimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_formatada, endereco, telefone FROM pessoa WHERE nome LIKE '%$teste%' ";
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $grupo[] = $row;
    }
    return $grupo;
}
```

Comment: faz um teste trocando $('#nomefiltrar').val() por 'leticia' no ajax, e como voce sabe que nao consegue recuperar? por causa do h1?

Comment: Troquei e mesmo assim não recuperou o valor

Comment: Sim, no <h1> não mostra nada

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Não consegui escrever nada no chat. Eu resolvi criar um botão próprio pra filtrar o campo pro relatório.